# Create a hexagonal grid where I can get the position of the corners

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, geometry

I find a lot of examples of creating a hex grid like the following. But I'm having a hard time understanding how I might have a list of the corners in a hex grid. Basically I'd want a character to move along the line of the grid instead of the center. so I want to grab the position of the next corner in the hex grid and move them there.

I was thinking of using a basic hex grid code to create the prefabs in the right place and then just add empty game objects on each corner of the prefab, but then I have a bunch of overlapping positions that are shared corners for each hexagon. I thought I could delete them if they are overlapping but it just all seems too brute force and hard to keep track of. I'd love to hear some ideas on approaching something like this. By the way I'd also want to know the center of the hex besides knowing the corners.

this code successfully creates a hex grid pattern where I can add a hex shaped game object to instance.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Grid : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Transform hexPrefab;

    public int gridWidth = 11;
    public int gridHeight = 11;

    float hexWidth = 1.732f;
    float hexHeight = 2.0f;
    public float gap = 0.0f;

    Vector3 startPos;

    void Start()
    {
        AddGap();
        CalcStartPos();
        CreateGrid();
    }

    void AddGap()
    {
        hexWidth += hexWidth * gap;
        hexHeight += hexHeight * gap;
    }

    void CalcStartPos()
    {
        float offset = 0;
        if (gridHeight / 2 % 2 != 0)
            offset = hexWidth / 2;

        float x = -hexWidth * (gridWidth / 2) - offset;
        float z = hexHeight * 0.75f * (gridHeight / 2);

        startPos = new Vector3(x, 0, z);
    }

    Vector3 CalcWorldPos(Vector2 gridPos)
    {
        float offset = 0;
        if (gridPos.y % 2 != 0)
            offset = hexWidth / 2;

        float x = startPos.x + gridPos.x * hexWidth + offset;
        float z = startPos.z - gridPos.y * hexHeight * 0.75f;

        return new Vector3(x, 0, z);
    }

    void CreateGrid()
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < gridHeight; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < gridWidth; x++)
            {
                Transform hex = Instantiate(hexPrefab) as Transform;
                Vector2 gridPos = new Vector2(x, y);
                hex.position = CalcWorldPos(gridPos);
                hex.parent = this.transform;
                hex.name = "Hexagon" + x + "|" + y;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Honestly your approach is fine. The only recommendation is to, after generating the overlapping corner objects, iterate through and delete any overlapping ones. Remember that if it works it's not stupid, and brute forcing doesn't matter if you're generating this once or a couple hundred times. It only matters if you're doing it every frame. Tbh any attempt to make this clever would do nothing but complicate what you already have.

Comment: Catlike Coding has a whole tutorial on Hex Maps, you may find some value in it: https://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/hex-map/part-1/